# Parse the result of the work 'masscan' in format ip:port

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I began to learn programming, i am trying to write a simple parser, but i confused. I will be very happy if someone helps me.

mres.txt

```
# Masscan 1.0.3 scan initiated Sun Dec 23 23:00:31 2018
# Ports scanned: TCP(1;80-80) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 192.168.1.1 ()    Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.1.1 ()    Ports: 801/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.1.2 ()    Ports: 801/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.1.2 ()    Ports: 445/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.1.3 ()    Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.1.3 ()    Ports: 8080/open/tcp////
Host: 192.168.1.3 ()    Ports: 21/open/tcp////
# Masscan done at Sun Dec 23 23:00:45 2018
```

I want to receive data in a format:

```
192.168.1.1 80, 801
192.168.1.2 801, 445
192.168.1.3 80, 8080, 21
```

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os

ports = []
ip = None

with open('mres.txt','r') as f:

for elem in f.readlines():

    if not elem.startswith('#'):
          if ip != None:
              if elem.split(' ')[1] == ip:
                  ports.append(elem.split(' ')[3].split('/')[0])
                  continue
              else:
                  print(ip + str(ports))
                  ports=[]
          else:
              #print('Unic: '+str(ip) + ' port: '+ str(elem.split(' ')[3].split('/')[0]))
              ip = elem.split(' ')[1]
              ports.append(elem.split(' ')[3].split('/')[0])
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, why are you printing 1 and 2? Consider using a [`defaultdict(set)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)

Comment: Sory i forgot to delete, this is me for myself....

Comment: I think you'd get a lot out of David Beazley's talk [Python's Built In Superheroes](https://youtu.be/lyDLAutA88s). Its 45 min long, but it's a very fun and helpful talk about Python data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This manipulates your data, and prints the output you want. I've tried to explain it as well as I can in the comments below, but please ask questions for anything that's not clear.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import socket

# build a dictionary of ip -> set of ports
# default dict is cool becasue if the key doesn't exist when accessed,
# it will create it with a default value (in this case a set)
# I'm using a set because I don't want to add the same port twice
ip_to_ports = defaultdict(set)

with open('mres.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        # grab only the lines we're interested in
        if line.startswith('Host:'):
            parts = line.strip().split()
            ip = parts[1]
            port = parts[-1]
            # split it by '/' and grab the first element
            port = port.split('/')[0]

            # add ip and ports to our defaultdict
            # if the ip isn't in the defaultdict, it will be created with
            # an empty set, that we can add the port to.
            # if we run into the same port twice, 
            # the second entry will be ignored.
            ip_to_ports[ip].add(port)

# sort the keys in ip_to_ports by increasing address
for ip in sorted(ip_to_ports, key=socket.inet_aton):
    # sort the ports too
    ports = sorted(ip_to_ports[ip])
    # create a string and print
    ports = ', '.join(ports)
    print(ip, ports)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use dict to handle data:
1) IP can be the key in Dict
2) List can be the value in Dict.

if needed, I can create sample code for you.